Transfer money from one mobile to another mobile(wallet) using NFC technology
Planning to develop a Mobile App to transfer money from one mobile device to another mobile using NFC and without using internet and POS device (NFC card), As we tap two mobile device, the mobile device has to connected via NFC and money need to be transferred.
Is there any source code available in any technology ?

Mobile devices dont contain money. So there is nothing to transfer.

It's Wallet to wallet transfer via NFC, is it possible ?

You should adapt title and text of your post was the hint.

Suppose we have two mobile devices which has wallets within them. I want to transfer amount from one wallet to other using NFC without using POS device. Is it possible?

At a hardware level all smartphone with NFC hardware can transfer data between 2 mobile devices but on iOS Apple have restricted that capability to themselves so it's not possible for you to develop an Apple App to do this. On Android it is possible but fairly complicated to do.
You would also need to add extra security if the data transfer had some value like money because at the NFC level it has none.
